# Throttling socket.io connections/reconnections

Tags: websocket, socket.io

We are experiencing an issue in production whereby if a group of users lose internet connection at the same time (such a group of users in the same store) and then all try to reconnect at the same time, or the nodejs service restarts and all ~2000 socket.io clients try to reestablish connection to the server the nodejs service will become overwhelmed and socket connections will start going into what seems like a never ending cycle of connect and disconnect.  This will slow down the service and the response time of other request like server assets and receiving api calls.

Last week we implemented a throttling package (toobusy-js) which appears to work fine except yesterday when the socket reconnection issue happened the throttler didn't appear to intercede.  We restrict clients to use web sockets as the transport only, no upgrading.

I'm wondering if the socket.io reconnection attempt would even register with toobusy-js because the protocol is web sockets already? If not how could I throttle socket.io connections/reconnections?  Or suggestions on how to oversome this?  The only way we can stop this currently is to send out a job that kills the users Chrome session, we can do this because we control the on-premise servers they work from, which not preferred to say the least.

Comment: Node.JS should be able to handle that many connections just fine. You can create your own timeout handler, and just delay new incoming connections. That is probably what that package is doing.

Comment: Node has no problem handling the few thousand socket connections at the start of the day as users log in over time.  It's the sudden reconnection of all sockets at one time when the service restarts that is the problem.

Comment: I have some more info on what is happening, after more testing and load testing.  First of all the toobusy-js throttling wasn't accounting for the incoming socket connections, I also had to add the throttling code within, "socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {".  When the server is overloaded with a bunch of socket connection requests (service restart for instance) then the sockets that are connected fine will ping timeout after 60 secs and try to reconnect adding more strain on the service, this turns into a very back cycle.  How to overcome this? Thoughts?

Comment: Disable auto reconnection on the client and handle it yourself. Eg. Implement a random timer between 30 and 60 seconds for it to reconnect.